# where to place cron jobs in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, codeigniter-3

I have 4 cron jobs to execute. Curently the files files reside outside application. I want to place them organised in  a folder.

cron1.php code below

```
$argc = $_SERVER['argc'];
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
// INTERPRETTING INPUT
if ($argc > 1 && isset($argv[1])) {
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']   = $argv[1];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $argv[1];
} else {
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']   = '/cron/clearuserloghistory';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/cron/clearuserloghistory';
}
require_once("index.php");
```

CASE 1: cron job executes when called from browser

> root
>   -application/
>   -index.php
>   -css/
>   -js/
>   -cron1.php
>   -cron2.php

CASE 2: How I want is like below:

> root
>   application/
>   -index.php
>   -css/
>   -js/
>   -crons/
>
> > -cron1.php
> >     -cron2.php

I tried putting above file in a folder called crons outside application in root(CASE 2) with below code change.

```
require_once("../index.php");
```

Executing cron file as case 2 location returned below error.

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Please suggest a correct location to include cronfiles inside crons folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: require_once("../index.php");
moved file inside to cron folder and changed code as above. Gets Error "Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php"

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Controller and name it something like Cron.php, also make sure to extend it with Core CI_Controller
than make a function do to whatever you want and access it like any other function, now create a cron job for it.

for security of cron tab don't put anything in it like session or permission checking just put a get variable in the function and declear it's value in the function and when accessing it put the value in the url as you do. this way only you will know the vale and if anybody wants to visit the cron controller it will automatically redirect them to your login or wherever you want them to redirect.

I hope it will help you